# How to implement this in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I implement this in Laravel 4?

```
$countryName = DB::only("SELECT f_iptocountry_country_name FROM t_iptocountry WHERE $visitorsIp BETWEEN f_iptocountry_begin_ip_num AND f_iptocountry_end_ip_num");
```

This is query is okay using Laravel 3.

Anyone?

Comment: You might want to change your username, johncena. Your questions may not get answered if people can’t see you.

Comment: I will change it next time.. thanks for your concern...

Comment: I was making a joke :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a model IPToCountry related to the table t_iptocountry and you are sure you won't have more than one country using the same range of IPs:

```
$country = IPToCountry::where('f_iptocountry_begin_ip_num', '>=', $visitorsIp)
                            ->where('f_iptocountry_end_ip_num', '<=', $visitorsIp)
                            ->first(['f_iptocountry_country_name']);

$countryName = count($country) > 0 ? $country->f_iptocountry_country_name : '';
```

Are you concerned about performance? To *really* use the BETWEEN clause in this case you have two options: a far more complicated set of Laravel instructions (maybe using anonymous functions) or use in part a raw query .

Using raw it becomes:

```
$country = DB::table('t_iptocountry')
                     ->whereRaw("'$visitorsIp' BETWEEN f_iptocountry_begin_ip_num AND f_iptocountry_end_ip_num")
                     ->first(['f_iptocountry_country_name']);

$countryName = count($country) > 0 ? $country->f_iptocountry_country_name : '';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. It's working! you're a genuis! :-). #IAmALaravelNewbie